# Why can't I see the monit binary in the process list after starting it?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, monit

I have monit running and working (I set up a dummy warning that is getting sent), but I don't see any binary called "monit" in the process list. Furthermore if I sort the processes by newest process, the only things I see are the processes relevant to monit sending out emails — I don't see the monit binary itself.

**more info**

I installed it with `apt-get monit`

I started it with `service monit start`

```
# ps -ef | grep monit
root     29985 23882  0 02:07 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto monit`
```

Comment: How did you install it? What command did you use to start it? What is the output of `ps -ef | grep monit`?

Comment: added that info in the question above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you didn't start it in the background. Uncomment the following line in `/etc/monit/monitrc`:

```
## Start Monit in the background (run as a daemon):
#
set daemon  120           # check services at 2-minute intervals
```

to run it as a daemon. Restart Monit and verify with `ps`, you will see something like this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep [m]onit
root      8530     1  0 09:10 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/monit
```

Comment: Ahhh hahaha, that was it. So I guess it was just doing one check and then quiting.